# How to add an image to a transparent box using css

Tags: html, css, transparent

So yeah guys, my English is not really good, but I think u can understand me. I created a transparent box and I want to add an image to it, but when I add the image, it also became transparent, what should I do?

This is my code:

```css
html { 
  background: url(Untitled-4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
text-align: center;
}
#main {
width: 700;
height: 400;
background:#FFFFFF;
margin: 25px auto;
border: solid 5px #191919
display:       inline-block;
padding:       8px 20px;
background:    #073763 url repeat-x;
border-radius: 5px;
color:         #fff;
font:          normal 700 24px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
text-align:    center;
text-shadow:   1px 1px 0 #000;
opacity: 0.5;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Dragon Kova Z: Fryzo prisikėlimas </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
</html>
<body>
<img src="filmo info.gif" alt="Mountain View" 
<div id="main">
<embed src="FLOW - HERO -Kibou no uta-.mp3"
 width="0" height="0"
 autostart="false"
 name="mysound"
 enablejavascript="true"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To preserve contents of an element to go semi-transparent, when inherited `opacity` property, there is a trick to apply transparency to your element without making the image or any content transparent. Set only the background color as transparent, like this -

```
#main {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

don't use opacity now.

Answer (score 1):

Here you fill the background solid but actual you need a transperent background in the div box so you will be aply to background rgba() function
then you be easilly apply

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dragon Kova Z: Fryzo prisikėlimas </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="filmo info.gif" alt="Mountain View"/> 
<div id="main">
    <embed src="FLOW - HERO -Kibou no uta-.mp3"
 width="0" height="0"
 autostart="false"
 name="mysound"
 enablejavascript="true"/>

    Hello
    Hows you ?<br>
    Fine.... :)
 </body>

html { 
  background: url(Untitled-4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
text-align: center;
}
#main {
width: 700;
height: 400;
background:rgba(10,12,200,0.2);
margin: 25px auto;
border: solid 5px #191919
display:       inline-block;
padding:       8px 20px;
background:    #073763 url repeat-x;
border-radius: 5px;
color:         #fff;
font:          normal 700 24px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
text-align:    center;
text-shadow:   1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```